# Group by aggregate function to count rows, map count to a user group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, aggregate

For those of you familiar with *Minecraft*, I am trying to count the number of blocks of each type broken by each user in a single SELECT query. I think that this is called a GROUP BY aggregate function. I think that I need to use multiple aggregate functions to accomplish my end-goal.

So far, I have only been able to:

- Count the number of blocks of each type that have been broken
- Count the total number of blocks broken by each user

I think that I need to use a GROUP BY function to COUNT the number of times that each block is broken, then GROUP by each user in a sub-query.

---

**Problem pseudocode:**

- SELECT the **player**, **block_id**, **count(*)** WHERE the **action_type** is equal to **"block-break"**
- COUNT the number times that a block has been broken (by counting the number of occurrences for each **block_id**)
- GROUP BY the **block_id**

**What I've tried:** ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLi3Z.jpg))

`SELECT player, block_id, COUNT(block_id)
FROM prism_actions
WHERE action_type = 'block-break' 
GROUP BY block_id;`

**Also:**([output])[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOdXv.jpg)

- This function appears to compute the appropriate value.

`SELECT player, block_id, count(*) as count from prism_actions where action_type = 'block-break' group by block_id,player order by block_id;`

---

**Table** (prism_actions)

`Field              Type
id                 int(11) unsigned
action_time        timestamp
action_type        varchar(20)
player             varchar(16)
world              varchar(255)
x                  int(11)
y                  smallint(5)
z                  int(11)
block_id           mediumint(5)
block_subid        mediumint(5)
old_block_id       mediumint(5)
old_block_subid    mediumint(5)
data               varchar(255)`

---

I have performed a similar GROUP BY aggregate query to count #(deaths|kills|blocks broken|blocks placed) per player

- This query works as expected, but only requires a single GROUP BY function
- Computes the SUM for each action based on the **action_type** (i.e. player-kill, player-death, block-break, block-place
- Output is available below:

`lower(player) kills deaths blocks_broken blocks_placed
joey            41    4           4911          2678
kate            74    1           4944          4762
bill           129    4           2782          1271
jack           335   12           12403         5886`

**Code:**

`SELECT LOWER(player), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 'player-kill' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS kills, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 'player-death' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS deaths, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 'block-break' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blocks_broken, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 'block-place' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blocks_placed 
FROM prism_actions 
WHERE action_type IN ('block-break', 'block-place', 'player-kill', 'player-death') 
AND LOWER(player) NOT IN ('creeper', 'fireball', 'environment') GROUP BY player;`

---

Thank you in advance.

I realize that my rep is low on StackOverflow, but I hope that this does not influence your answer, or lead to any form of discrimination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ROLLUP modifier here to get what you're after.

```
SELECT player, block_id, count(*) as count 
from prism_actions 
where action_type = 'block-break' 
group by player, block_id WITH ROLLUP
order by block_id;
```

This will give a record set similar to

```
Player | Block | Count
NULL     NULL    100
1        NULL    100
1        1       75
1        2       25
```

Where player =1 and block = NULL is the grand total, below that is the count by block type.